# How to uncheck a radio button in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time with this. **ID number always changes (this case _t2342)** so I can't select it properly. I'm trying to remove 'checked="true' from input field using JavaScript. Is it possible? I only have an array of 2 items.

```html
<table id="inputFormPopup:_t2342">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input checked="true" id="inputFormPopup:_t2342:0" name="inputFormPopup:_t2342" onchange="document.getElementById('inputFormPopup:submitInptExtendPricing').click();document.getElementById('inputFormPopup').reset();" type="radio" value="ef">
        <label
          for="inputFormPopup:_t2342:0"> Effective Date</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="inputFormPopup:_t2342:1" name="inputFormPopup:_t2342" onchange="document.getElementById('inputFormPopup:submitInptExtendPricing').click();document.getElementById('inputFormPopup').reset();" type="radio" value="ex"><label for="inputFormPopup:_t2342:1"> Expiration Date</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please note that alot of solution require Jquery. Is it possible with plain javascript?

Comment: Everything possible in jQuery can be done in vanilla JS

Comment: Did you attempt anything yet? Show us the JavaScript that you tried.

Comment: `document.getElementById("inputFormPopup:_t2342:0").checked = false;`

Comment: Chazsolo, they used Jquery was trying to do this with plane JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one table in the page, you can start from the table for selecting the target element:

```
document.querySelector('table input[type=radio][checked=true]').checked = false;
```

Or by using *attribute starts with* selector:

```
document.querySelector('table[id^=inputFormPopup] input[type=radio][checked=true]').checked = false;
```

Comment: this worked :) thank you document.querySelector('table[id^=inputFormPopup] input[type=radio][checked=true]').checked = false;

Answer (score 2):

Get DOM element and set `checked` attribute to `true` like is shown below:

```
var $button = document.getElementById('inputFormPopup:_t2342:1')
$button.setAttribute('checked',true);//this will check the radio
//$button.setAttribute('checked',false);//this will uncheck the radio
```

Comment: Or set it to `false` as the case may be.

Comment: Hi Samvel, thank you but in this case inputFormPopup:_t2342:1 will change everytime to something like inputFormPopup:_t2344_3

Comment: This is a bit pedantic but imo variables prefixed with `$` should be reserved for jQuery objects.

Comment: @user10343270 you need to have some unique stable way to identify the radio will it be id or the n-th child or something else. You should choose something.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is changing, you can consider selecting the button usong jquery. For example:
`$('table > tr > td > input[type=radio]').setAttribute('checked', false);`

Comment: checkboxID always changes :(

Comment: Thank you I was looking for plain JS solution if it's possible